# SQL: Append string after pattern matching for multiple occurrences

Tags: sql-server

I have following data:

```
    declare @tmptable TABLE
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Text NVARCHAR(200)
    )
    insert into @tmptable values ('PREFIX_1.A + PREFIX_2.B')
    insert into @tmptable values ('PREFIX_1.C + PREFIX_2.E + PREFIX_1.X')
    insert into @tmptable values ('PREFIX_2.D')
    insert into @tmptable values ('')

    declare @suffix nvarchar(20) = '_new'
```

I want to replace/ append data as follows:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
PREFIX_1.A_new + PREFIX_2.B_new
PREFIX_1.C_new + PREFIX_2.E_new + PREFIX_1.X_new
PREFIX_2.D_new
```

**What I have tried:**

```
    select REPLACE(Text,
                    SUBSTRING(Text, CHARINDEX('.', Text) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ',Text )),
                    SUBSTRING(Text, CHARINDEX('.', Text) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ',Text )) + @suffix
                  )
   FROM @tmptable                   
    where Text like ('%PREFIX_1%') or Text like ('%PREFIX_2%')
```

**NOTE:
What I want:**

**Append suffix to the text present after the dot.**

**Input:**

```
PREFIX_1.A + PREFIX_2.B - PREFIX_1.C * PREFIX_1.D
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PREFIX_1.A_new + PREFIX_2.B_new - PREFIX_1.C_new * PREFIX_1.D_new
```

Find text just after dot(.) and append suffix to it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: The better solution is to stop storing delimited data in your table; then you don't have to try and add stuff after every occurrence of a pattern, as it'll only appear once. Fix your design, fix the problem.

Comment: SQL 2008 version

Comment: FYI, 2008 is now completely unsupported (and has been for several months). It's strongly recommended you upgrade as soon as possible. If you are using unsupported technology, you should always mention and tag that in your question as well, as the users here will *assume* you are using supported versions.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data all you have to do is replace all occurrences of `' +'` with `@suffix + ' +'` and append also `@suffix` at the end:

```
select id, replace(Text, ' +', @suffix + ' +') + @suffix as Text
from tmptable
where Text like ('%PREFIX[_]1%') or Text like ('%PREFIX[_]2%')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=129ed007d870da445a88389911bf81c0).
Results:

```
> id | Text                                            
> -: | :-----------------------------------------------
>  1 | PREFIX_1.A_new + PREFIX_2.B_new                 
>  2 | PREFIX_1.C_new + PREFIX_2.E_new + PREFIX_1.X_new
>  3 | PREFIX_2.D_new
```

Comment: Cue the OP saying they have data like `'PREFIX_1.C + NOPREFIX123 + PREFIX_1.X'` ;)

Comment: *"Cue the OP"* They haven't (yet). I just wouldn't be surprised

Comment: @Larnu this is why I say: *For this sample data...*

Comment: @Larnu sorry, I was googling the word *cue*. I really did not know what it means!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods.

The first one uses a recursive CTE and `FOR XML` to deconstruct & reconstruct the strings.

The second uses a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` & `STRING_AGG` to cut them up & glue the parts back together.
Requires Sql Server 2017+ though.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
> (
>   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   [Text] NVARCHAR(200)
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into #tmpTable ([Text]) values 
>   ('PREFIX_1.A + PREFIX_2.B')
> , ('PREFIX_1.C + PREFIX_2.E + PREFIX_1.X + PREFIX_2.Y')
> , ('PREFIX_2.D + PREFIX_9.E + PREFIX_1.Y')
> , ('PREFIX_1.E')
> , ('')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(30) = '%PREFIX[_][1-2][.]%';
> DECLARE @delim VARCHAR(1) = '+';
> DECLARE @suffix NVARCHAR(30) = '_new';
>
> WITH RCTE AS
> (
>     SELECT id
>     , text+@delim as str
>     , 1 as lvl
>     , 0 as pos1
>     , CHARINDEX(@delim,text+@delim) as pos2
>     FROM #tmpTable
>     WHERE Text LIKE (@search)
>
>     UNION ALL
>
>     SELECT id, str, lvl+1
>     , pos2+1
>     , CHARINDEX(@delim, str, pos2+1)
>     FROM RCTE
>     WHERE pos2 > pos1
> )
> SELECT id
> , ISNULL(a.NewText, t.Text) as [Text]
> FROM #tmpTable t
> OUTER APPLY
> (
> SELECT STUFF(CAST(q.parts AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),1,3,'') as NewText
> FROM
> (
>      SELECT CONCAT(' ',@delim,' ', RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(str, pos1, pos2-pos1))), CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(str, pos1, pos2-pos1) LIKE @search THEN @suffix END)
>      FROM RCTE c
>      WHERE c.pos2 > c.pos1
>        AND c.id = t.id
>      ORDER BY c.lvl
>      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
> ) q(parts)
> ) a
> ORDER BY id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Text                                                             
> -: | :----------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | PREFIX_1.A_new + PREFIX_2.B_new                                  
>  2 | PREFIX_1.C_new + PREFIX_2.E_new + PREFIX_1.X_new + PREFIX_2.Y_new
>  3 | PREFIX_2.D_new + PREFIX_9.E + PREFIX_1.Y_new                     
>  4 | PREFIX_1.E_new                                                   
>  5 |
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(30) = '%PREFIX[_][1-2][.]%';
> DECLARE @suffix NVARCHAR(30) = '_new';
>
> SELECT id, NewText
> FROM #tmpTable t
> CROSS APPLY
> (
>    SELECT 
>     STRING_AGG(
>       CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(s.value)),
>        CASE
>        WHEN s.value LIKE @search
>        THEN @suffix 
>        END),' + ') AS NewText
>    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.[Text],'+') s
> ) a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | NewText                                                          
> -: | :----------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | PREFIX_1.A_new + PREFIX_2.B_new                                  
>  2 | PREFIX_1.C_new + PREFIX_2.E_new + PREFIX_1.X_new + PREFIX_2.Y_new
>  3 | PREFIX_2.D_new + PREFIX_9.E + PREFIX_1.Y_new                     
>  4 | PREFIX_1.E_new                                                   
>  5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dda40ebd412d5d7fee7fd74f3fe63eab)*